# Alt-Tab doesn't switch window after launch emacsclient

Tags: emacs, launcher, ubuntu-11.10, emacsclient

I wanted to open a new file in Emacs from shell in a new buffer in an existing window, so I used `emacsclient`.

After I launch `emacsclient`, it opens the file in a new buffer, as I wanted, but then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work and I need to click with the mouse on the top panel to get to another window.

May somebody know how to solve this problem? Or maybe open new file in a new buffer without `emacsclient`?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

`emacsclient` command I'm using:

```
emacsclient --no-wait  -n $*
```

Comment: I'm not sure why alt+tab not works, but you should able to switch between window with `c-x 5 o`

Comment: What windowing environment are you using? Also, FYI your operating system is three and a half years old. Canonical has released five versions of Ubuntu since then, including two Long Term Support releases. You may want to consider upgrading.

Comment: I'm using Gnome classic. I can't upgrade my OS because it is not my own pc. c-x 5 o causes the same problem, Alt-tab doesn't work after that.

Comment: Have you tried `C-x C-f /path/to/file RET` to open a (new) file?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question - I want to open it from shell.

Comment: Any special reason why you are passing `--no-wait` *and* `-n` to `emacsclient`? According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html), they are the same thing. Also, I can't use `emacsclient` the way you describe. When I run `emacsclient --no-wait -n $*` I get "emacsclient: file name or argument required".

Comment: When I open files with emacslient in GNOME (v3) it seems to switch to Emacs without actually displaying it. Thus alt+tab once will switch *back* to whatever window ran emacsclient, and then alt+tab again will focus Emacs "properly". Could this be the same problem?

Comment: @itsjeyd, `emacsclient --no-wait -n $*` is probably defined as a function somewhere. The `$*` bit contains all arguments passed to the function itself.

Comment: Thanks. @Biffen, It's not my problem, when I open it from Shell it actually displaying it, and then Alt+Tab doesn't work.